# The inserted value have a lot of commas in mysql after using implode method

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I have a page that allow user to borrow sport equipments. I have used a text field  so user can put the sport equipment quantity at there. But, after the quantity's value inserted in mysql, it have a lot of commas beside the value. For example, user choose 9 quantity, so the commas appear beside the 9.

**Value image**

[image]

**view.php**

```
  <td align='center'><input name='kuantiti[]' type='text' maxlength='2'  
  size='1'></td>
```

**process.php**

```
   $kuantiti = implode(',', $_POST['kuantiti']);

   if (isset($_POST['pinjam'])) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO user_request(nama, noic, jawatan, peringkat, email,  
   peralatansukan, kuantiti) values ('$_SESSION[nama]', '$_SESSION[noic]', 
   '$_SESSION[jawatan]', '$_SESSION[peringkat]', '$_SESSION[email]',  
   '$peralatansukan', '$kuantiti')";
```

Comment: Please print the array using this function  print_r($_POST['kuantiti'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happened because of null values in the array. use `array_filter()` function to avoid this.

```
$kuantiti = implode(',', array_filter($_POST['kuantiti']));
```

Comment: Thank u mith!! Now my problem is solved. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

why are you imploding an integer?
use  name="kuantiti" instead of "kuantiti[]"

Comment: dear sir Azad Khan. Are u want to show me any snippet code?or just the statement above?

Comment: <td align='center'><input name='kuantiti' type='text' maxlength='2' size='1'></td>
<?php $kuantiti =  $_POST['kuantiti'];?>

Comment: cannot trust stackoverflow. it always show my answer half. when i edit the answer. its full. but when i post it. its half. so disgusting

Comment: so, do I  need to delete the implode method in process.php?

Comment: and remove the [] form html name also

Comment: Haha I understand your situation sir. Btw thank u sir for ur help. But,the value cannot be inserted in mysql. Same like my problem before. Anyway, I've used  mith solution. Now, my problem is solved. Thanks again sir Azad Khan for your suggestion.

Comment: good to see your problem solved. but no need to make an array for quantity. quantity is an integer. and you should directly store it.